# Exit for loop without using a break statement

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
public static void enterInts()
{
    int i = 0;
    int[] userArray = new int[9];
    
    System.out.println("Enter up to 10 integers, type 0 when done");
    
    for(i = 0; i < userArray.length; i++)           
    {
        if (keyboard.nextInt() != 0)    
            userArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        else
            break;
    }//for
    posOrNeg(userArray);
}//enterInts
```

My professor REALLY hates break statements and continue() in loops, so I would like to know if there is anyway to exit this for loop once "0" is typed without using one.

Comment: don't call `keyboard.nextInt()` two times per loop iteration, you're loosing numbers

Comment: you need to store keyboard.nextInt() inside a variable, and than you can add another condition to the for loop

Comment: Your message says "up to 10 integers" but your array only accepts 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to call `nextInt()` in the loop condition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userArray.length && (userArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt()) != 0; i++);
```

Comment: this will work, but for the love of God please do not actually write your loops this way. His professor may hate breaks, but everyone else will hate this.

Comment: Maybe the professor will learn a lesson.

Comment: As a professional for 25 years, having done code reviews for more than half that time as both a peer and a leader, I would NEVER approve that code in any production system. Just ick!

Comment: @E-Riz Might want to steer clear of the [JDK](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#L4942) then.

Answer (score 1):

The **break;** and **continue;** are the best way to control the flow of a loop. Anyway, It's a reality that professors around the world are haters of that.

With this kind of nonsense limitation, you have to be creative if you want to end up with a code that doesn't look like shit.

My suggestion, is a little bit obfuscated and makes to code harder to understand, but is the closest thing to "break":

```java
int length = 10;
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)           
{
    i = length; // This produces the same effect as break.
}
```

Good luck with that, stay cool and keep things nice and clean!

Answer (score 0):

First, as someone else said, you should read nextInt() into a variable so you can assign it later. Your code will ask for a number, and then if that number is not zero, it will forget what the number was and then ask for another number to be input, which will get assigned.

As for potential solutions: One idea would be to move the loop to its own method, and then you could just use "return" in lieu of "break". It's effectively the same concept, but avoids the break keyword. I worry that he may not like that either though. It's not clear why he doesn't like break, so it's hard to say.

Another solution would be to replace the for loop with a while loop, get the next input at the end of the loop, and then have the conditional for the loop include the number not being zero.

Comment: The reason why the professor doesn't like the continue and break, and probably return is more likely to be due to the "single exit point rule". Professors around the world misunderstand this rule and try to radically avoid any kind of alternative path. the best way to fight this argument is to show them why it doesn't make any sense by throwing an exception instead of a guard clause return.

Answer (score -1):

just replace break; with return;

Comment: Fine, but what about the last line: `posOrNeg(userArray)` ?

Comment: If his professor hates continue and break, for sure is going to also hate return... 